# Как получать обновление переменной через AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, pjax

Вопрос, как во время выполнения pjax запроса, передавать измененное состояние переменной offset с модели во View файл?

Пока идет перебор, переменная offset изменяется, в модели во время запроса она меняется(100, 200, 300), мне нужно чтобы это так же отображалось и в view.

p.s за ошибки и плохой пример кода прошу извинить.

Например,

Есть модель myModel с методом myCounter
Переменная offset по дефолту равна 100.

```
public function myCounter()
{
    Для примера, мне нужно сделать тут перебор данных
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $communityData['totalPages']; $i++)
    {
        $someData = $offset;
        $offset += 100;
    }

    return  $someData
}
```

Есть контроллер SiteController с методом index.

```
public function index($someData)
{   
    $getCounter = new MyCounter($someData);
    $totalCounter = $getCounter->myCounter();

    return $this->render('index', ['totalCounter' => $totalCounter]);
}
```

Есть View index.php в котором добавлено Pjax

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= Html::beginForm('index', 'get', ['data-pjax' => '']) ?>
<?= Html::input('text', 'someData') ?>
<?= Html::submitButton() ?>
<?= Html::endForm() ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Есть js файл, в котором пока идет Pjax запрос, показываю Loader

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.loader').hide()

     $(document).on('pjax:send', function() {
         $('.loader').show()
     })
     $(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
         $('.loader').hide()
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю в чем тут проблема, в своем виде сделайте поле и передавайте туда $totalCounter

```
\yii\bootstrap\Html::input('text', 'counter', $totalCounter);
```